# How to attach a XStream converter just for a certain element?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

It is easy to set a converter for a certain type (http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html gives an example):

```
xstream.registerConverter(new SqlTimestampConverter());
xstream.registerConverter(new DynamicProxyConverter());
```

I would like to register a converter, but on different element names. The Converter interface does not offer the name of the element.

For example: A date should be converted to a detailed string if the element name (property name) will be in `<longDate>` but short if in `<shortDate>`. How can I add different converters based on the property name? Something like xstream.registerConverter( Class classtype, propertyname, converter ) didn't exist but would be nice.

I know that I can use a specialised version of a PrettyPrintWriter but that seems to much work for this simple job. Any other ideas?

BTW: I could use an annotation @XStreamConverter(XXX.class) but I don't want to use annotations. I want my bean free of any annotation.

Answer (score 6):

Use `registerLocalConverter()` instead of `registerConverter()`.

```
xstream.registerLocalConverter( MyClazz.class, "property", new MyConverter() );
```